# iOS camera rotates properly in safari but not in web app mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, camera

I am building a web app that will allow the user to take a picture and upload to a folder on server and then the image is displayed on a gallery page.  The upload portion works fine but I am having some problems with iOS.  When I run the app in safari, everything works fine when you access the camera, you can rotate camera and take portrait or landscape pictures and they upload and render properly on the gallery page.
Problem is when it runs in web app mode from the homescreen...if you launch access the camera while in portrait mode, the camera launches but if you turn the phone in camera mode the image rotates too as if it is locking the portrait mode.
Is there are way programmatically, to allow the camera to rotate as it does when it runs in safari?

Here is my code, perhaps it is incorrect?

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:100%;">
                <span style="text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word;">
                Please choose a picture: 
                <br></span>
                <input id="uploadImage"  type="file" accept="image/*" name="uploadFile" onchange="PreviewImage();">
                <img id="uploadPreview" style="height:120px; width: auto;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
};
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" ><br>
Please wait for window to close after uploading
</form>
```

Anyone else experience this camera glitch in an iOS webapp?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have run into a similar issue and would love to hear if you solved it?

Comment: No i didnt find a solution.... I have learned that Apple is making it harder and harder to create web apps that closely replicate native app functionality.  They don't make money on web apps, but the do on native.  Let me know if you figure it out though...thanks

Comment: Well, to be honest I came across several other devs with this issue and after much playing around, I tried to wrap everything inside of a Cordova wrapper, which solved the problem. It seems that it's a limitation of UIWebView in a web app, but I don't think there will be a solution from Apple anytime soon, for the reasons you've already indicated,

Comment: The best workaround for me is to lock the orientation of the device. Obviously not ideal. PS - it works in mobile safari, just not as a web clipped website on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in iOS 10

We had the same issue and it works as of this morning.